# Eclipse OCL google.inject creation exception

Tags: ocl, ecore

I use OCLinEcore in my project and use constraint for validation. The following error appears:

> 1-Error injecting method, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing contribution for type: org.eclipse.xtext.ui.containers.JavaProjectsState ...

I use OCL 6.0.0.
It works in Eclipse Mars2 Release 4.5.2 but it didn't work in our coding environment. Which jars could be blocking OCL plugins?

Comment: Eclipse Mars2?! Could you upgrade to maintained versions of the tools? Java changed a lot too.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch! Eclipse OCL is now on 6.14.0. Mars was over 5 years ago. Major disruption has occurred through changes in Java in that time so I suspect that some aspect of your configuration is inconsistent. Recent Eclipse OCL releases have been tested on Oxygen and later. I recommend that you ensure that you use a consistent recent release. (I cannot fully recommend the very latest Eclipse OCL for which a 6.14.1 maintenance release is imminent.)